# How to get text of a child div within a div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Say I have a div container with multiple divs with some width and height. I want to get the text within a div clicked.

```
<div id="containId">
<div>Sometext1
<div class="description">This is a desc</div>
</div>
<div>Sometext2
<div class="description">This is a desc</div>
 </div>
<div>Sometext3
<div class="description">This is a desc</div>
</div>
<div>Sometext4
<div class="description">This is a desc</div>
</div>
<div>Sometext5
<div class="description">This is a desc</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I make it so that when the user clicks on a div within containId, I can get the text into a variable (just the Sometext# part and not the description divs within those divs)?

Comment: Why do you need jQuery to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#containId > div').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).contents().map(function() {
        if(this.nodeType !== 3) return null;
        return this.nodeValue;
    }).get().join('');
});
```

It works as follows: `.contents()` returns a jQuery object containing *all* child nodes, not only elements nodes. `.map()` is used to filter out non-text nodes and retrieve the text value of text nodes.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qBVZ6/)

This will retrieve the value of all text nodes, not only the first one. If you only want to get the value of the first text node, use [@karim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706800/218196) (simpler).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#containId > div").click(function () {
   alert(this.firstChild.nodeValue);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q8VRe/5

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
$("#containId div").click( function(){
   var x = $(this).text();
});
```

If you want only the text value from the first node you can use:

```
var x = this.firstChild.nodeValue
```

If you want to exclude the second level of divs from the click, you can use:

```
$("#containId div").click( function(){
    var x = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
}).find("div").click( function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `.text()` will also include the text of descendants.